# Meaning of the title "Now Inhale" by Eric Frank Russell

Tags: short-stories, title-explanation

Eric Frank Russell's story "Now Inhale" - discussed [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103039/short-story-with-character-who-plays-tiddlywinks-as-a-death-sentence) is one I read decades ago and don't currently have access to a copy of. Therefore I'll ask here: what is the significance of the title "Now Inhale" to this story of a man who manages to delay his execution at the cost of mental health? Is it a reference to some then-well known bit of culture that I'm not familiar with?

Comment: The summary linked to in the answer describes the game-delayed-execution as "choosing the time of your last breath".  Maybe the implication is that the protagonist has been metaphorically holding his last breath for the years he's been playing the game, and now he can finally draw another one?

Comment: "*“Looks like I haven’t, the way you put it,” observed Taylor dryly. “I’m right on top of the world without anything to lose except my breath.” He brooded a bit, then asked, “When am I due for the noose?”*

Comment: "Now he could never be sure that he was not about to become the lead character in a literally breathless scene." There are lots of these. :)

Comment: Ah.  Don't know why I didn't make that connection.

Comment: The story is available to read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v63n02_1959-04_EXciter-LennyS/page/n29/mode/2up).

Comment: Thank you.  Anyone want to compose an answer?

Comment: @DavidW - I've had a read through several of the [anthologies in which this story was published](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55624); *13 Above the Night*, *Aliens from Analog*, and *Major Ingredients: The Selected Short Stories of Eric Frank Russell*. There's no help there

Comment: @Andrew - At the moment all we have is guesswork. Russell, for example, used this exact expression in a story he wrote just a year earlier called *The Space Willies*" -  *"Pork and beans, pork and beans, Holy God, pork and beans," squawked the control-tower speaker with swiftly fading strength. "Get undressed because I want to test your eyes. **Now inhale.** Keen by name and keen by—*" In that instance, it was in relation to a medical examination - https://youtu.be/rA0SBSnnL78?t=42

Comment: Perhaps the title refers to part of the meditative technique observed by the "priests in the Temple of Benares" as they play the game that Taylor introduces to delay his execution?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply that the method of execution the protagonist escapes is strangulation - having his breath cut off by a rope. His guard describes the process enthusiastically, and there are references to it in the story, most particularly the last line when he is told playing a game might make him feel better, and responds, "I'll be hanged if I do."

Comment: This isn't a very clear answer. It's already been speculated in the comments beneath the question that the title likely has something to do with the main character being due to be hanged. What does the title mean more precisely though? Who is being asked to inhale? Why? When? And by whom? And are you just guessing, or can you provide compelling evidence as to the writer's intent?

Comment: This appears to be your own opinion, unsupported by any evidence

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood the intention or etiquette of this site; if so I apologize. It didn't occur to me to think of it as opinion because it seems extremely obvious. I just reread the story and counted at least a dozen references to breath, necks, rope, etc. The story is from the protagonist's point of view, and he speculates many times about the prospect of death.

Comment: Didn't spot the limit when I edited: Maybe I misunderstand the intention or etiquette of this site; if so I apologize. It didn't occur to me to consider it opinion because it seems so obvious. The story is from Taylor's POV, and he speculates throughout about death, so he is the one asked to inhale - and strangulation means you can never exhale again. Why? Because he's about to be executed. When? When the game is over (ie never). By whom? His executioner. All this in his mind, because the story is about his mindset rather than the "gimmick" which readers always think of as the focus.